# Jquery trigger on alert option selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, alert

I have a jquery that produces an alert. If the alert has 2 options to select (eg. ok, cancel), i  would like to trigger a function depending on the value selected.[image]

so i essentially need to identify if there is an alert present, if it has more than 1 option or an "ok" option, then trigger a function if option 1 or "ok" is selected.

**UPDATE**
I have no control over the alerts displayed, as i'm using a CMS. What i would like to do is trigger my function once "ok" is selected.

Comment: `if (confirm('Are you suar?')) { // +ve } else { // -ve }`

Comment: @tushar please see update. I'm not the one producing the alert, i just want to trigger my function depending on the selection.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `confirm`function

```
if (confirm('Your customize message ')) {
    alert('Thanks for confirming'); //here you can call your function
} else {
    alert('Another Message'); 
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/8aec4q7n/)

Comment: please see update. I'm not the one producing the alert, i just want to trigger my function depending on the selection.